# UIAlertViewDelegate in separate class crashes application

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uialertview, nsobject

I'm having difficulties with `UIAlertView` delegation in class other than `ViewController`.
Everything is fine until user clicks the `OK` button - then app crashes with

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address 0x8)
```

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DataModel.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DataModel *dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    [dataModel ShowMeAlert];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

**DataModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataModel : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
- (void)ShowMeAlert;
@end
```

**DataModel.m**

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel
- (void)ShowMeAlert;
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"View did load!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertView protocol

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Index: %d", buttonIndex);
}

@end
```

- If code for showing alert and it's delegation methods is in `ViewController` - works perfectly.
- When I remove `UIAlertDelegation` method `...didDismissWithButtonIndex...` -
  works without delegation.
- When I set `UIAlertView delegate` to `nil` -
  works without delegation.

Any clues what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  DataModel *dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
  [dataModel ShowMeAlert];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

you are allocating a DataModel local variable which will be deallocated by ARC at the end of the scope. Hence, when dismiss is executed, your delegate is not there anymore. The fix for this is to store your `DataModel` in a `strong` property of your view controller. This way it will not be deallocated. The you would do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
  [self.dataModel ShowMeAlert];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```